# How to make the grass look more realistic using a particle system

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, scene

I'm using a hair particle system to create grass in my scene. I've added 3 different blades of grass and 60,000 particles of each. But still Im not getting a realistic grass effect. Is there anything im doing wrong?

I'm using cycles.

[image]

Comment: look at the image behind the model. It is not only the shape of grass that is important, but the many different tones and colors.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean, But that HDRI is only there for lighting. There is going to be bushes and trees to cover up the difference

Comment: No i mean the grass is not always green, but yellow green, light green, dark blueish green and so on.

Comment: You'll get the biggest visual benefit via Material, try using a Colorramp node to define a range of colors like shades of green and yellow. Also, try enabling Interpolated Children in the Hair Physics properties and explore those settings, namely Clumping and Kink.

Comment: as jackiejake says, use the ColorRamp, plug the Input > Object Info node and plug its Random socket into the ColorRamp. Also, play a bit with the rotation of your herb, they all seem to be rotated in the same direction, put a bit of randomness (there's an Advanced option in the Hair panel, have you enabled it?)